# VBA Excel Cells.Value does not read a line broken

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Hope you can help me with this problem.

I have a macro that catches a cell.value and take it to an outlook.body, but the value of the cell has been copied directly from word, and so some of the lines are not broken as intended.

For example, the value taken from the word document is:

```
"Hello xxx

I've been waiting for the files that you said you were going to sent

Don't forget our meeting this week.

See you
Leonardo."
```

But when this value is sent to the outlook.body, the line breaks are removed:

```
"Hello xxx I've been waiting for the files that you said you were going to sent Don't forget our meeting this week. See you Leonardo."
```

What can I do?

Comment: [What's the code?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Show your macro and how you'r doing your concatenation. You probably just need to insert line feeds (vbCrLf)

Comment: you can also look into `.htmlbody`, not sure it will help in this case, but it may provide more flexibility

Answer (score 1):

Excel uses LF to break a line within a cell.  Outlook uses CR LF to break a line.

Try:

```
OutlookValue = Replace(ExcelValue, vbLF, vbCR & vbLF)
```